# How to rename Pandas columns based on mapping?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where column `Name` contains values such as the following (the rest of the columns do not affect how this question is answered I hope):

```
Chicken
Chickens
Fluffy Chicken
Whale
Whales
Blue Whale
Tiger
White Tiger
Big Tiger
```

Now, I want to ensure that we rename these entries to be like the following:

```
Chicken
Chicken
Chicken
Whale
Whale
Whale
Tiger
Tiger
Tiger
```

Essentially substituting anything that has 'Chicken' to just be 'Chicken, anything with 'Whale' to be just 'Whale, and anything with 'Tiger' to be just 'Tiger'.

What is the best way to do this? There are almost 1 million rows in the dataframe.

Sorry just to add, I have a list of what we expect i.e.

`['Chicken', 'Whale', 'Tiger']`

They can appear in any order in the column

What I should also add is, the column might contain things like "Mushroom" or "Eggs" that do *not* need substituting from the original list.

Comment: Is the Single key words always show firstly ?

Comment: do you already have a list with all the single words you expect?

Comment: @BENY it can be in any order

Comment: @Ben.T Yes sorry I'll add that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `str.extract`

```
#l = ['Chicken', 'Whale', 'Tiger']

df['new'] = df['col'].str.extract('('+'|'.join(l)+')')[0]
Out[10]: 
0    Chicken
1    Chicken
2    Chicken
3      Whale
4      Whale
5      Whale
6      Tiger
7      Tiger
8      Tiger
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Comment: Would this work if the column contained other names like "Mushroom" which don't need substituting?

Comment: @caasswa as long as you adding then into your list it should work

Comment: hmm... I see.... okie that might be ok :)